# Assign default security group to Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, security-groups

I have created a Elastic Beanstalk environment and I have a rails app running which is great.  However I am unable to assign is to the default security group.

[image: Current config]

I have added a screenshot to this post showing the current security group assign.  Any help would be appreciated on assigning the .default group!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a config file to attach existing security groups in `.ebextensions`

**FILE:** `./.ebextensions/ec2-securitygroup.config`

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    SecurityGroups: name-of-security-group-1, name-of-security-group-2
```

NOTE: Do not use the *Group Name* or *Group ID*, its the *Name* field/column

**DOCS:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration

**SecurityGroups**

Lists the Amazon EC2 security groups to assign to the EC2 instances in the Auto Scaling group in order to define firewall rules for the instances.

You can provide a single string of comma-separated values that contain the name of existing Amazon EC2 security groups or references to AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup resources created in the template. Security group names are case sensitive.

If you use Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) with Elastic Beanstalk so that your instances are launched within a virtual private cloud (VPC), specify security group IDs instead of security group names.

***elasticbeanstalk-default***

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following ebextensions

```
$ cat .ebextensions/ec2-security-group.config
option_settings:
    aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
       SecurityGroups: sg-1234567
```

Lists the Amazon EC2 security groups to assign to the EC2 instances in the Auto Scaling group in order to define firewall rules for the instances.

> You can provide a single string of comma-separated values that contain
>   the name of existing Amazon EC2 security groups or references to
>   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup resources created in the template. If you use
>   Amazon VPC with Elastic Beanstalk so that your instances are launched
>   within a virtual private cloud (VPC), specify security group IDs
>   instead of a security group name.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration

Also you can modify AWSEBSecurityGroup resource via [cloudformation template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html)

Comment: This works for me, however the problem is, Beanstalk add another security group with this one and adds 0.0.0.0 for 22. This is security issue the environment. I am trying to figure out how to stop EBS to add another SG to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Amazon Console, select EC2. Select your instance. Right-click and select "Networking / Change Security Groups".